# How to create/download RSA key in p12 format for Docusign JWT authorization

Tags: jwt, docusignapi, netweaver, docusignconnect

I got into very odd situation were im not able to create JWT sign token in sap netweaver server.
currently the encryption is done using p12 file instead of pem file in sap server.

Docusign only provide the RSA key in .pem format. Which at the moment is not feasible for me.

Is there a way to download/create RSA key in .p12 format like it is provided in google api's instead of text/pem format or how can we create JWT sign token using RSA private key in .pem format in sap netweaver server.

Thanks and regards,
Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign creates the public/private key pairs for JWT signing. You download the private key in pem format from DocuSign. Something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAuv1+cIU9ashbXUxkJXzsqoeN3rNjcwcRMI17njwHpOh+ljV6
CNLRu+VAvtFdluK/TN+idb7jlFBe2CIdNbev/sYX1lB0+zJw1vsgSSk31d9vdPQb
n5R0FZUTsAYXv27JB6kc5N/6n2uroeNmeABkZZTLvXSmibYOjVYeB+Ig5HBS2Xxw
...lines omitted...
O2F4bIUOh1pdRydwHH0bMLXfyqn7sOxdEJwIq6Is5DwKeLJUEyfiuaGGjHQBfs+u
eoySeQKBgQC1aRTK4g4c5dgxdywCRTje/kUh5Ion6vFLLrTmEKtV9LFyFvLtFrVL
iX9G3qm0a3raSNwXylfbs88tPDrTGaTEM2opt5YpDWExpS7sLknDQxGcCzgyjTqc
/p6p+tOzgoc+osBMCNvBPS8tEAmdfTk7LFxVh8UY49JIpwoAnJ7c5Q==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

### Converting to p12 format

You can run open source applications locally to do this conversion.

There are also online converters available. See [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+pem+to+p12+online) for a list.